# Bliking lines runnig across the screen

Tags: 18.10

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.10 in a all-in-one hp, I just wanted to migrate from Windows. It seemed that everything is fine but it gets some problems with the screen, it's blinking lines all over it. There is no lag or any other troubles and when it ran Windows that never happened.

Please help me to fix it. Sorry my bad english.

[image: I took this with my phone]

Comment: I had a somewhat similar thing. Can you try to install, but when offered to install updates select no. I have resolved the issue by not updating my kernel.

Comment: Actually, that's what I did when I installed it. And thanks to your clue, I tried to install 16.04 LTS but the same has happened.

Comment: What happens when you start from the USB but chose to use Live version rather than installing it? Do you still get the lines then?

Comment: Yes, I realized when try with any version the lines appears even running Live.

Comment: I'm afraid i'm out of my depth then. I would advise filing a bug report, maybe somebody will help you. Because you machine is still booting up you can do that by opening a terminal and typing `ubuntu-bug`